# Hazelcast symmetric encryption check with java

Tags: java, hazelcast

Can I check how symmetric encryption works in Hazelcast with Java code or with something another tool? I want to see encrypted values comed from Hazelcast if it's possible.

Config:

```
    SymmetricEncryptionConfig symmetricEncryptionConfig = new SymmetricEncryptionConfig();
    symmetricEncryptionConfig.setEnabled(true);
    symmetricEncryptionConfig.setAlgorithm("Blowfish");
    symmetricEncryptionConfig.setSalt("asdfdsasdfsadfsadf");
    symmetricEncryptionConfig.setPassword("passwasdsadasdord");
    symmetricEncryptionConfig.setIterationCount(28);

    Config config = new Config();
    config.getNetworkConfig().setSymmetricEncryptionConfig(symmetricEncryptionConfig);

    ListConfig listConfig = new ListConfig();
    listConfig.setName("ISP");
    listConfig.setMaxSize(20);
    config.getListConfigs().put("ISP", listConfig);

    config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
    config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter");

    HazelcastInstance server = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Comment: Probably - you need the cyphertext, the encryption key and the algorithm and mode that was used to encrypt the plaintext. Then update your question with the alogorithm details.

Comment: Symmetric encryption is a Hazelcast Enterprise feature, you cannot use it with Hazelcast Open Source IMDG. Are you using Hazelcast Enterprise?

Comment: @AlparslanAvci Unfortunately no. I have task with adding symmetric encryption to hazelcast. In documentation I found only configs with XML and no example for testing how it works. In production using enterprise version of it. Will it work on prod, if I only set params to XML?

Comment: Yes, it you use Enterprise and set the parameters to XML, it will work. Please find an example of it here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/network-configuration/symmetric-encryption

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems valid.

To try it yourself you can ask for a Hazelcast Enterprise trial license which is valid for 30 days - https://hazelcast.com/hazelcast-enterprise-download/

The symmetric encryption internally works on Hazelcast packets level. The flow is similar to the [PacketEncoder](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.11/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/nio/tcp/PacketEncoder.java). What makes the difference is the byte output is encrypted by a chosen cipher.

**Additional notes**

- Symmetric encryption is only used in member-to-member communication! The client-to-member is not encrypted;
- Symmetric encryption can't be used together with TLS;
- Using TLS is preferred over the Symmetric encryption in Hazelcast.